# How do I crop a layer in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers, crop

Sometimes, I'll have several layers on an image and I want to crop one of them. NOT resize it, crop it. Every technique I've tried simply crops EVERYTHING, not just the layer I'm working on. I have to delete the layer, crop the original image that it's from, then re-paste it into what I'm working on. I'd also like know how to rotate a layer without rotating everything else in the entire image.

Comment: Have you tried making a selection then click *Layer > Crop to selection*?

Comment: I'm not a GIMP user, but in *most* raster editing applications you **don't** "crop a layer" -- You select what you want removed from the layer and the delete it from the layer. "Cropping" only refers to the *entire* document, not individual layers.

Comment: @Scott Not the same thing. What you describe fills the layer with transparency but it keeps it size. The crop resizes it.

Comment: I know. **Layers** don't typically have sizes which are independent of the *document*. **All** layers in a document have the *document size*.

Comment: @Scott, in GIMP you can crop a layer to have a size that is not dependent on the document size. So, in this regard GIMP is different from Photoshop and others.

Comment: Fair enough. `:)` That seems to me to merely be application-specific proprietary term usage though.. All it's *really* doing is making a selection and then removing anything outside that selection so it's *transparent*. It's not *actually* "cropping" by definition.. but... I'll be the last person to state that GIMP is the only app which may use such non-standard terminology in its app. Adobe does it all the time. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume you had selected a layer as an active layer which can easily be done using the layers menu:

[image]

This makes the ants yellow to indicate the active layer

[image]

If you then want to crop just this active layer make sure you had ticked the "current layer only" box in the crop tool menu

[image]

Now, when you apply the crop tool a new active layer will be created as cropped from the previous active layer:

[image] [image]

To crop a selection from a layer choose *Layer > Crop to selection* from the top menu.

Comment: This can also be done by making an ordinary selection (e.g. with the rectangle select tool), then clicking *Layer > Crop to Selection*

Comment: @BillyKerr: **cool** - thanks for that! Even after years Gimp still surprises me with things that of course can be done.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

> I'd also like know how to rotate a layer without rotating everything else in the entire image.

Use the Rotate tool for intereactive editing:

[image]

Or use *Layer>Transform>Arbitrary rotation* if you know exactly what you want to do.